# How can i get current layout language in firefox extension with Linux/Mac?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xpcom

This can be done with user32.dll on Windows. But how can i get it on Mac/Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [nsILocaleService.getSystemLocale()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsILocaleService#getSystemLocale%28%29) for that:

```js
var localeService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/intl/nslocaleservice;1"]
                        .getService(Components.interfaces.nsILocaleService);
var sysLocale = localeService.getSystemLocale()
alert(sysLocale.getCategory("NSILOCALE_MESSAGES"));
```

This should work regardless of operating system.